# updating a complex object in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, locking, mutex

I want to compute a heavily io-bond task which use internet and then save result in 2d-array, in a single process mode it would take many days to complete.

i went to make it multiprocessor by updating a row in each process.

```py
    class MatrixData:
        def __init__(self, size):
            self.size = size
            self.dist_matrix = [[0.0] * size] * size
            self.last_not_given_row = 0
            self.last_save = 0

            self.resolved_list = mp.Array('b', [False] * size)

        def save_row(self, row_index, data, lock):
            lock.acquire()
            try:
                print('lock')
                self.last_save= self.last_save + 1
                if self.last_save % 2 == 0:
                    self.save_file()
                self.resolved_list[row_index] = True
                for i in range(self.size):
                    self.dist_matrix[row_index][i] = data[i]
            finally:
                print('unlock')
                lock.release()
```

i use some other parameters like `last_save` to save it to file in small periods.

i use locks to ensure process-safe manner but when i start a process it will make new space and corrupt data.

```py
lock = mp.Lock()
    for i in range(12):
        p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(data_calculator, MatrixData_obj))
        p.start()
        plist.append(p)

    for p in plist:
        p.join()
```